# is _trackEvent counted as a page view?

Tags: google-analytics

in Google Analytics, if I use _trackEvent, will it increase the page view count?

I know there is a parameter to mark the event as a non-interaction in order to not affect the calculated bouce rate. But when this parameter is not set (default), will events also count as page views?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It shouldn't, no. According to the [Google Analytics Event Tracking documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html):

> Additionally, pageview calculations are unaffected by user activity tracked using the Event Tracking method.